# Calling exe with input and output file paths matlab

Tags: matlab, exe

I want to use an exe in matlab in a way that I could also mention input and output path of the input and output files as follows:

file.exe (parameter) (input_file_path) (output_file_path)

The above line shows how I write my command in DOS prompt.

Mushi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [*`system`*](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/system.html) command to achieve this.

```
system(['file.exe ' parameter ' ' input_file_path ' ' output_file_path ]);
```

If arguments are fixed you can simply run

```
>>!file.exe parameter input_file_path output_file_path
```

Comment: I found it like this --> system(['file.exe parameter ' input_file_path ' ' output_file_path]);. Anyway, it worked perfectly. Thanks a loads.